# Sourcetree 2.1.2.5 - Shows "Uncommitted changes" yet nothing is pending

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a problem that I have not been experienced before. Even though I have nothing to commit and have tried to reset my branch to the latest commit Sourcetree shows `Uncommitted changes`.

[image]

According to the Atlassian forums there is usually two reasons:

1. You have many, many unstaged files in your working directory that
   get listed in SourceTree. This causes Git/Hg to take quite some time
   going through all the files, and so SourceTree waits on Git/Hg to
   report back. - **Tried hard reset so any changed should have been reverted. If I edit one file it shows up in Sourcetree.**
2. Your system specifications aren't quite up to scratch. Really you
   need about 20GB free disk space, and some decent memory backing you
   up. - **154GB free HDD space. 8GB ram free.**

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/quot-Uncommitted-changes-quot-yet-nothing-is-pending/qaq-p/94549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [jblopez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45887814/345659) this is a bug (still unresolved almost 4 months later).

The workaround is to disable LibGit2 integration.
Tools -> Options -> Git -> and tick the Disable LibGit2 integration checkbox down the bottom of the tab.
Restart Sourcetree and the phantom commits disappear.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. I had the same problem with Sourcetree 2.3.1.0. Do you know if there are any drawbacks with disabling the LibGit2 library?

Comment: @frieder I've been running with it disabled for 2 months with no problem -  except my local changes sometimes take a while to appear as Pending changes. Unsure if it is related.

Comment: yes I have the same problem, it takes a while to show the uncommited changes. Sometimes I have to change the sorting of the files (in a commit) then the files appear.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently an open bug in SourceTree for this very issue.
[SRCTREEWIN-7112](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7112)