# Sourcetree says unstaged changes but command line doesn't

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

### Problem

I have come across an annoying problem where my Sourcetree always thinks I have 4 outgoing changes but the command line does not.

### Attempts

I am not able to reset, force a clean, force a checkout, change to a clean new branch or anything of the sort to remove these files. Once these files show up they are always present regardless of branch. If I change, add or remove a different file they show up correctly in both Sourcetree and git.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940990/sourcetree-2-1-2-5-shows-uncommitted-changes-yet-nothing-is-pending) thread that is very similar but a big difference is their outgoing doesn't even show any changes.

### Visual

[image]

### Additional Information

- Windows 7
- Sourcetree 2.3.1.0
- git 2.13.2  (see the same issue with embedded vs system git)

### Suggestions

Short of deleting the whole repository folder which may or may not work, can anyone think of another way to remove these?

Thank you,

Comment: According to https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7112 this is a known Sourcetree bug and disabling LibGit2 works around it.

Comment: I tried that when I saw that issue via the link in the description, it didn't change it. The issue that is described there is that the graph portion shows uncommitted changes but the log doesn't. My issue is that all of sorucetree thinks there is uncommitted changes but command line knows there isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```
 git config core.fileMode false
```

### Explanation

This appears to be an issue related to the core.fileMode setting. I started experiencing the reverse of this question additionally (where my Cygwin terminal started to show unstaged changes as well), and git diff on one of the files stated:

```
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

The solution to this was to turn that config off which seemed to fix both issues.